# Cannot read/access dynamically updated data in Webdriver DOM

Tags: c#, selenium, dom, dynamic, webdriver

Page has a table populated with user1's information. When node is clicked to select user2, table data is dynamically updated and page is not reloaded.

FindElement can find the element, but cannot see the new text in that element

Using explicit or implicit waits do not work.

```
        do
            {
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                vehicleTitle = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='vehicleRateSummary']/tbody/tr/th")).Text;
                driverTitle  = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='vehicleRateSummary']/tbody/tr[3]/th")).Text;
            }
            while (vehicleTitle == "");
```

HTML ...

```
<html debug="true" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<body class="ui-layout-container" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px;">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="TransRateSummary.aspx" id="form1" onsubmit="return false;" novalidate="novalidate">
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="/Production/WebResource.axd?d=pynGkmcFUV13He1Qd6_TZGbw1_qCDhf0FaNR4rXz3tF1n9KNi_pFKeZ4y9KlfWh_VnUER0IdmFID-JSZAPDbpA2&t=636776509224055265" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="/Production/WebResource.axd?d=5GcSkSOyaAp9rgkHHDGLyws2fsmpXV5D9CKfy_myT9ytS0MLAqZ17ed-Ovveu2-B62tStCMGNKmroCqdqbMSvQ2&t=636776509224055265" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
<div>
<div id="revisionsContainer" class="ui-layout-center ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-center ui-layout-pane-hover ui-layout-pane-center-hover ui-layout-pane-open-hover ui-layout-pane-center-open-hover" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 406px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 909px; width: 1492px; z-index: 0; display: block; visibility: visible;">
<div id="revision0" class="revision" style="display: inline-block;">
<div id="vehicle1" class="vehicle" style="display: inline-block;">
<table id="vehicleRateSummary" class="summary">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="lj8ptbold" colspan="11">Vehicle 1 - Slot 1</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr>
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="summaryRow">
<tr>
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr>
<tr class="summaryRow">
<tr>
<tr class="summaryRow">
<tr>
<tr class="summaryRow">
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="vehicle2" class="vehicle" style="display: none;">
<table id="vehicleRateSummary" class="summary">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="lj8ptbold" colspan="11">Vehicle 2 - Slot 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="lj8pt" colspan="11">ERNIE STENSETH</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr class="factorRow">
<td class="lj8ptbold">Base Premium</td>
<td class="lj8pt italic"/>
<td class="rj8pt">31.990</td>
<td class="rj8pt">22.820</td>
<td class="rj8pt">4.000</td>
<td class="rj8pt">19.150</td>
<td class="rj8pt">12.430</td>
<td class="rj8pt">14.650</td>
<td class="rj8pt">50.670</td>
<td class="rj8pt">1.000</td>
<td class="rj8pt">1.000</td>
</tr>
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr>
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="summaryRow">
<tr>
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr class="factorRow">
<tr>
<tr class="summaryRow">
<tr>
<tr class="summaryRow">
<tr>
<tr class="summaryRow">
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="westPane" class="ui-layout-west no-padding no-margin ui-layout-container ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-west" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 0px; right: auto; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 929px; z-index: 0; width: 398px; display: block; visibility: visible;">
<div id="revisionTreeContainer" class="ui-layout-center ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-center" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 356px; height: 551px; width: 376px; z-index: 0; display: block; visibility: visible;">
<div id="navBtns" class="navBtns ui-layout-south no-padding no-margin ui-layout-container ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-south" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; margin: 0px; top: auto; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; width: auto; z-index: 0; height: 348px; display: block; visibility: visible;">
<div id="" class="ui-layout-resizer ui-layout-resizer-south ui-draggable-handle ui-layout-resizer-open ui-layout-resizer-south-open" title="Resize" style="position: absolute; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-size: 1px; text-align: left; overflow: hidden; z-index: 2; cursor: s-resize; bottom: 350px; width: 398px; height: 6px; left: 0px;">
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="transId" name="transId" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" id="pn" name="pn" value=""/>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<input type="text" id="form_0_DisableAutoSubmit" value="" class="v_ignore" style="display: none;"/>
</form>
<div id="sumdiv" style="display: none;"/>
<span id="ModalBox_WaitDialog" style="display: none;">
<div id="ModalBox_MessageDialog" style="display: none;">
<div id="ModalBox_PromptDialog" style="display: none;">
<div id="" class="ui-layout-resizer ui-layout-resizer-west ui-draggable-handle ui-layout-resizer-open ui-layout-resizer-west-open" title="Resize" style="position: absolute; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-size: 1px; text-align: left; overflow: hidden; z-index: 2; cursor: w-resize; left: 400px; height: 931px; width: 6px; top: 0px;">
</body>
<script src="chrome-extension://ehemiojjcpldeipjhjkepfdaohajpbdo/googleChrome.js"/>
</html>
```

Running this just gets stuck in this loop as the text of the element never equals anything other than "".

Comment: Are you sure `Text` is the attribute which will have the text? Can you share the html of the `vehicleRateSummary`

Comment: Yes, this same code works perfectly on the first pass. It's only when it tries to do the same thing on the second table of data that it fails.

Comment: You are using implicit wait incorrectly. When you call that line, it doesn't actually wait... it just sets the wait timeout and it lasts for the life of the driver.

Comment: You've added WAY too much HTML. Just include the relevant HTML... like the table with user 1 and then the table with user 2. Most of the HTML you've included has no data in it unless you've removed it all.

Comment: @JeffC I initially only added the relevant bit, but added the rest when asked in a discussion below.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for element to be visible, and than get text:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
vehicleTitle = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//table[@id='vehicleRateSummary']/tbody/tr/th"))).Text;
driverTitle = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='vehicleRateSummary']/tbody/tr[3]/th")).Text;
```

Try with `textContent`:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
do
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    vehicleTitle = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].textContent", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='vehicleRateSummary']/tbody/tr/th")));
}
while (vehicleTitle == "");
```

Comment: Waits do not work. In code above it continuously loops, rechecking the text in the element. If at anytime it finds any text in the element other than "" it would break the loop. It just continues to loop.

The problem is that the DOM is not updated because the page is never reloaded.

Is there not a way to force the DOM to refresh to re-read the new data on the screen?

Also, reloading the page is not an option. Doing so just brings up a 'session timeout' page.

Comment: @HeadlyvonNoggin can you share url?

Comment: No, it's a test environment inside our network. You wouldn't be able to access it. The question is more general. The problem is that unless the browser loads the page, the webdriver DOM is not updated with the new data. I've scoured this site and others thinking there's got to be a way to force the DOM to re-read the page, but can't find anything.

Comment: Share complete HTML after user2 selected

Comment: Updated HTML block above to include full page

Comment: Your shared HTML is broken. The table is inside `script` tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190528/discussion-between-sers-and-headlyvonnoggin).

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to verify the text, there there is no mighty need to have Selenium do this specifically. So here is a solution that does it via Jquery.

Note, `driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait` only needs to ever be set once, unless you are changing the value to something different.

Also note, my example requires more than implicit wait between loops.

```
            using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions;

            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            do
            {
                vehicleTitle = driver.ExecuteJavascript<string>("return $('#vehicleRateSummary > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > th').text()");
                driverTitle  = driver.ExecuteJavascript<string>("return $('#vehicleRateSummary > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > th').text()");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); //Milliseconds
            }
            while (vehicleTitle == "");
```

Now, I can't guarantee that works without the page to test it myself, but you can make sure that works by going to your browser Developer Console, and pasting the raw JQuery at the appropriate time you wish to pull the text `$('#vehicleRateSummary > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > th').text()`

Now, if that doesn't work, let me know. Particularly, if your page does not use JQuery, we can work something else out. If this doesn't work, it might help more for us to see the html within the table after it updates with the values you are searching for (vehicleRateSummary table).

Also, **important note:** **th** is normally a table header row cell. Whereas **td** is normally a body row cell. Are we sure that is what we should be looking for here? Special case? Just making sure we are indeed searching for the right elements.

Now, here is a solution that can be used everywhere in your project, which will rewrite your above code (if you'd like it):

```
    //Goes in some static tools class. Must be a static class.
    private static void WaitUntil(this IWebDriver driver, Func<bool> Condition, float timeout)
    {

        float timer = timeout;
        while (!Condition.Invoke() && timer > 0f)
        {

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            timer -= 0.5f;

        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

    }

     //And your new code 
     driver.WaitUntil(() => driver.ExecuteJavascript<bool>("return $('#vehicleRateSummary > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > th').text().length > 0"));
     driver.WaitUntil(() => driver.ExecuteJavascript<bool>("return $('#vehicleRateSummary > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > th').text().length > 0"));
```

Comment: Yes, this same code works before the data is changed, so the xpath path is working.

Comment: The "driver" above is "IWebDriver", which does not have a definition for "ExecuteJavascript", so I'm unable to use your method.

Comment: You must add  `using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions;`

Comment: I added Selenium.Support.Extensions, but still get the same error

Comment: There is something wrong with your dll's then. That is a method in that dll. Assuming you are using Nuget packages, I would recommend getting latest. This would be under OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions.WebDriverExtensions, which is under the WebDriver.Support dll in your project references. I have version 3.141.0.0, myself. The Nuget package that contains it is "Selenium.Support.3.141.0".

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the help.

I've figured out the issue. It turns out the fields that I thought were being changed when selecting the other view were just hidden. The updated data was not replacing the data in the original fields. They were located in a lower hidden window.